# Dplyr groupby name and rolling average from last n events by date

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a rolling average over the last 3 events of a person(name).
I have the date which I would like to use the most recent of the 3 events. Some people might be in the `DF` less than others and that's ok.

**Code to create dataframe:**

```
library(dplyr)

# Create DataFrame

df<- data.frame(name=c('CAREY.FAKE','CAREY.FAKE','CAREY.FAKE','CAREY.FAKE','CAREY.FAKE','CAREY.FAKE',
                      'JOHN.SMITH','JOHN.SMITH','JOHN.SMITH','JOHN.SMITH','JOHN.SMITH','JOHN.SMITH',
                      'JEFF.JOHNSON','JEFF.JOHNSON','JEFF.JOHNSON','JEFF.JOHNSON',
                      'SARA.JOHNSON','SARA.JOHNSON','SARA.JOHNSON','SARA.JOHNSON'
                      ),
               GA=c(2,2,2,2,2,20,2,2,2,2,2,20,2,2,2,20,2,2,2,20),
               SV=c(2,2,2,2,2,20,2,2,2,2,2,20,2,2,2,20,2,2,2,20),
               GF=c(2,2,2,2,2,20,2,2,2,2,2,20,2,2,2,20,2,2,2,20),
               SA=c(2,2,2,2,2,20,2,2,2,2,2,20,2,2,2,20,2,2,2,20),
               date=c("10/20/2016","10/19/2016","10/18/2016","10/17/2016","10/16/2016","10/15/2016",
                      "10/20/2016","10/19/2016","10/18/2016","10/17/2016","10/16/2016","10/15/2016",
                      "10/20/2016","10/19/2016","10/18/2016","10/17/2016",
                      "10/20/2016","10/19/2016","10/18/2016","10/17/2016"
                      ),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**DF:**

```
name        GA  SV  GF  SA  date
CAREY.FAKE  2   2   2   2   10/20/2016
CAREY.FAKE  2   2   2   2   10/19/2016
CAREY.FAKE  2   2   2   2   10/18/2016
CAREY.FAKE  2   2   2   2   10/17/2016
CAREY.FAKE  2   2   2   2   10/16/2016
CAREY.FAKE  20  20  20  20  10/15/2016
JOHN.SMITH  2   2   2   2   10/20/2016
JOHN.SMITH  2   2   2   2   10/19/2016
JOHN.SMITH  2   2   2   2   10/18/2016
JOHN.SMITH  2   2   2   2   10/17/2016
JOHN.SMITH  2   2   2   2   10/16/2016
JOHN.SMITH  20  20  20  20  10/15/2016
JEFF.JOHNS  2   2   2   2   10/20/2016
JEFF.JOHNS  2   2   2   2   10/19/2016
JEFF.JOHNS  2   2   2   2   10/18/2016
JEFF.JOHNS  20  20  20  20  10/17/2016
SARA.JOHNS  2   2   2   2   10/20/2016
SARA.JOHNS  2   2   2   2   10/19/2016
SARA.JOHNS  2   2   2   2   10/18/2016
SARA.JOHNS  20  20  20  20  10/17/2016
```

**Code to create rolling average:**

```
df_next <- df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(last_three_mean = mean(tail(GA,SV,GF,SA, 3))
```

**ERROR:**

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: length(n) == 1L is not TRUE.
```

**The Desired result:**

```
name        GA  SV  GF  SA
CAREY.FAKE  2   2   2   2
JEFF.JOHNS  2   2   2   2
JOHN.SMITH  2   2   2   2
SARA.JOHNS  2   2   2   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `arrange` by 'Date' and then use `summarise_at` to get the `mean` of multiple columns after grouping by 'name'

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
   group_by(name) %>%
   arrange(name, mdy(date)) %>% 
   summarise_at(2:5, funs(mean(tail(., 3))))
   #or select the column by matching the name pattern
   #summarise_at(vars(matches("^[A-Z]{2}$")), funs(mean(tail(., 3))))  
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  name            GA    SV    GF    SA
#  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 CAREY.FAKE       2     2     2     2
#2 JEFF.JOHNSON     2     2     2     2
#3 JOHN.SMITH       2     2     2     2
#4 SARA.JOHNSON     2     2     2     2
```

---

Or another option is to make use of `top_n` and then do the `summarise_at`

```
df %>% 
   group_by(name) %>%
   top_n(mdy(date), n = 3) %>%
   summarise_at(2:5, mean)
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply weights to average by date? Say most recent is 50%, the second is 30%, and the third is 20%?